# keras Bidirectional layer using 4 dimension data

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, word-embedding

I'am designing keras model for classification based on article data.

I have data with 4 dimension as follows

```
[batch, article_num, word_num, word embedding size]
```

and i want to feed each (word_num, word embedding) data into keras Bidirectional layer

in order to get result with 3 dimension as follows.

```
[batch, article_num, bidirectional layer output size]
```

when i tried to feed 4 dimension data for testing like this

```py
inp = Input(shape=(article_num, word_num, ))
# dims = [batch, article_num, word_num]

x = Reshape((article_num * word_num, ), input_shape = (article_num, word_num))(inp)
# dims = [batch, article_num * word_num]

x = Embedding(word_num, word_embedding_size, input_length = article_num * word_num)(x)
# dims = [batch, article_num * word_num, word_embedding_size]

x = Reshape((article_num , word_num, word_embedding_size), 
             input_shape = (article_num * word_num, word_embedding_size))(x)
# dims = [batch, article_num, word_num, word_embedding_size]

x = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(50, return_sequences = True), 
                  input_shape=(article_num , word_num, word_embedding_size))(x)
```

and i got the error

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer bidirectional_12: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want it to touch the `article_num` dimension, you can try using a `TimeDistributed` wrapper. But I'm not certain that it will be compatible with bidirectional and other stuff.

```py
inp = Input(shape=(article_num, word_num))    

x = TimeDistributed(Embedding(word_num, word_embedding_size)(x))

#option 1
#x1 shape : (batch, article_num, word_num, 50)
x1 = TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(50, return_sequences = True)))(x)

#option 2
#x2 shape : (batch, article_num, 50)
x2 = TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(50)))(x)
```

Hints:

- Don't use `input_shape` everywhere, you only need it at the `Input` tensor.
- You probably don't need any of the reshapes if you also use a `TimeDistributed` in the embedding.
- If you don't want `word_num` in the final dimension, use `return_sequences=False`.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick and accurate answer! I achieved what i want with TimeDistributed wrapper even though i am unclear how it works.

Comment: Well.... it just ignores the `article_num` dimension (first dimension after the batch size). As if each article were an individual sample in the batch.